# Why yield does not work in this construct?

Tags: python, yield

I cannot understand why this yield construct gives me only one run in the for loop:

```
class myRange():
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.current = first - 1
        self.last = last

    def __iter__(self):
        self.current = self.current + 1
        if (self.current <= self.last):
            yield self.current


for n in myRange(1, 10):
    print(n)
```

which produces:

```
1
```

---

EDIT: Kind of weak question! I was tricked by the name of the `__iter__` funciton...

Comment: `__iter__` is not going to make a loop for you, you need to do that yourself. Maybe something like `while self.current < self.last:` Then you can get rid of the `if`.

Comment: It **does** work. Your generator yields at most a single item... why did you *expect* it to produce more than 1 item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `__iter__` function needs to loop. As it is, it only yields once, so your loop only prints one value.

```
class myRange():
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.current = first
        self.last = last

    def __iter__(self):
        while self.current <= self.last:
            yield self.current
            self.current += 1
```

Comment: Might not be the scope of the question but having yield in __iter__ function does not make sense to me. OP should either use __next__ or not use the special function.